# Converting PDF/ DOCX to mac iwork pages(5.5.3) format

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf, converters, docx

A friend of mine wants me to convert a file {he gave me *.pdf and *.docx versions of it} to the format of his mac os. He told me it's Iwork pages(5.5.3). But I am a linux user(ubuntu 14.04) and I couldn't find a way for it.

further I was told the format is (*.PAGES) on iwork. So the requirement should be getting those either PDF or DOCX version in *.pages format.

Please let me know if anything out there would help me to do this in Ubuntu.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A .PAGES file is actually a .zip file with a changed extension.  You can find some more information here: http://blog.cleverly.com/permalinks/346.html